# Dance Pair Algorithm(from a programming contest)

Tags: java, algorithm

The question was as follows:
Input:

3 10

1 2 3

12 11 101

where 3(n) is number of boys and girls 10(k) is accepted height difference
next 2 lines are heights of girls and boys respectively

1 2 3 are height's of the 3 boys

and 12 11 101 are heights of 3 girls

now we have to find the maximum number of pair of  one girl and one boy
such that their height difference is less than or equal to k.

Given:

```
      K >= 1 and less than 10^9,

      N >=1 and less than 10^5,

      heights(both boy an girl)>=1 and less than 10^9.
```

A girl cant dance with more than one boy and vice versa

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> boyGirlsPair= new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> girlBoysPair= new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
    int dancingPairsCount = 0;
    int count = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = scan.nextInt();
    long K = scan.nextLong();
    long[] boysHeightList = new long[N];
    long[]  girlsHeightList = new long[N];
    scan.nextLine();
    while (count<N) {
        boysHeightList[count]=scan.nextLong();
        count++;
    }
    scan.nextLine();
    count =0;
    while (count<N) {
    girlsHeightList[count]=scan.nextLong();
    count++;
    }
    scan.close();
    for (Integer boysHeightListIter =0;boysHeightListIter<N;boysHeightListIter++) {
        for (Integer girlsHeightListIter=0;girlsHeightListIter<N;girlsHeightListIter++) {
            if (Math.abs(boysHeightList[boysHeightListIter] - girlsHeightList[girlsHeightListIter]) <= K) {
                if(boyGirlsPair.containsKey(boysHeightListIter))
                {
                    List<Integer> pairValue = boyGirlsPair.get(boysHeightListIter);
                    pairValue.add(girlsHeightListIter);
                    boyGirlsPair.put(boysHeightListIter,pairValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    List<Integer> pairValue = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    pairValue.add(girlsHeightListIter);
                    boyGirlsPair.put(boysHeightListIter,pairValue); 
                }
                if(girlBoysPair.containsKey(girlsHeightListIter))
                {
                    List<Integer> pairValue = girlBoysPair.get(girlsHeightListIter);
                    pairValue.add(boysHeightListIter);
                    girlBoysPair.put(girlsHeightListIter,pairValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    List<Integer> pairValue = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    pairValue.add(boysHeightListIter);
                    girlBoysPair.put(girlsHeightListIter,pairValue);
                }   
            }
        }
    }
   if(girlBoysPair.size()<=boyGirlsPair.size())
   {
       System.out.println(girlBoysPair.size());
   }
   else
   {
       System.out.println(boyGirlsPair.size());
   }
 }
}
```

The basic algorithm i used is formed 2 hashMaps one with keys as boys and values are list of girls they can dance with and another hashmap with keys as girls and values are boys who they can dance with.The smallest of 2 hashmaps are the maximum pairs that can be formed.This passed this basic test case of the contest,but failed for all other cases.Want to know one case where my algorithm won't work and if possible other solutions to this problem.

Comment: Not sure if it's optimal but it could be solved with maximal matching on bipartite graph. What are the number of boys and girls? (to know if it's feasible)

Comment: maximum number of boys is 10 ^ 5 and number of boys and girls are always equal

Comment: This question is definition of maximal matching! just google it and you will find your answer

Comment: @Lrrr my question also as to what mistake i made in my algorithm?Are there any flaws?

Comment: @Lrrr There might be a more efficient solution since the edge are not arbitrary, the height factor might help to optimize it

Comment: @KaushikSivakumar I dont see any reason why your algorithm should work.

Comment: @amit I think already existed solutions for maximal matching are fast enough, but any optimization regards to height could be interesting

Comment: Maximal will TIme-out. Greedy will not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can be easily solved using two-pointers approach.

I will try to describe this method with an example of a problem.

Given two arrays (A and B) sorted in ascending order, and an integer x. we need to find i and j, such that a[i] + b[j] is equal to X.
i and j our pointers, at first step i is points to the first element of a, and j points to the last element of b.

```
i = 0; j = b.size() - 1;
```

Move first pointer one by one through the array a, and correct position of the second pointer if needed

```
while (i < a.size())
{
   while(a[i] + b[j] > X && j > 0) j--;
   if (a[i] + b[j] == X) writeAnswer(i, j);
   i++;
}
```

Here, we can use a greedy approach.In this problem, we need to sort the both of height arrays. We keep two indices i for boys and j for girls.

Here is a c++ implementation-

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#define sint long long int

int main() {
    sint n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    assert(1<=n && n<= 100000);
    assert(1<=k && k <=1000000000);
    sint a[n];
    sint b[n];
    for(sint i =0 ; i< n  ; i++)
    {
            cin>>a[i];
            assert(1<=a[i] && a[i] <=1000000000);
    }
    for(sint i =0 ; i< n ; i++)
    {
            cin>>b[i];
            assert(1<=b[i] && b[i] <=1000000000);
    }
    sint i = 0;
    sint j = 0;
    sort(a,a+n);
    sort(b,b+n);
    sint value = 0;
    while(i < n && j < n)
    {
        if(abs(a[i] - b[j]) <= k)
        {
            i++;
            j++;
            value++;
        }
        else if(a[i] < b[j])
            i++;
        else
            j++;
    }
    cout<<value<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Let's also discuss a O(N^2) approach to the question-

Create a bipartite graph, both partites will contain N vertices. In first partite each vertex will represent a boy. Similarly each vertex in second partite will represent a girl. Now there will an edge between a pair of boy and girl if difference between their heights is less or equal to K. Maximum bi-partite matching in the given graph will be our answer.

Comment: I've tried to understand your solution but I failed to find a connection between this and question, I think either your solution is wrong or you didnt describe your solution good enough

Comment: I am pretty confident, ( maybe like 200%) that my code is correct. Why don't you submit it yourself? https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/epiccode/challenges/dance-in-pairs ;)

Comment: @user3907480 Thanks:) .It helps .Have a question though can you also help out as to why my algorithm wont work.?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that boys and girls are either short or tall and that the only valid pairs are short-short and tall-tall. If there are 10 short girls and 1 short boy and 1 tall girl and 10 tall boys, then the short boy dances with a short girl and the tall girl dances with a tall boy and no one else dances, for a total of 2 pairs, while all 11 girls and all 11 boys have someone with whom they can dance, so your algorithm returns 11.